# Counting the iteration in sapply

Tags: r

I'm using sapply and drawing plots. But I couldn't give different colors for each line I'm drawing using sapply. Is there a way I can increment a variable for each time sapply is called and use that variable(VARIABLE) for changing the color using plot_colors[VARIABLE]

```
    plot_colors <- c("blue","red","forestgreen","black")
    sapply(unique(ab$region[ab$region]), FUN=graphplot, REG=ab, tl=z, num=num+1)
    graphplot <- function(l, REG, tl, num) {
            dl <- REG[REG$region == l, tl]
            datel <- REG[REG$region == l, "date"]
            dl <- cbind(as.numeric(rownames(REG[REG$region == l, ])), REG[REG$region == l, tl])
            lines(dl, type="l", pch=2, col=plot_colors[num])
            num <- num + 1
    }
```

Here is the full code.

```
    avg_data <- read.table("qes.tbl", header=T, sep=",")
    avg_data
    #        dl <- avg_data[avg_data$region == "prod", "AveElapsedTime"]
            #datel <- avg_data[avg_data$region == "prod", "date"]
    #Creating the graph pdf in the below path to give as a link in the mail
    FL <- 20120631
    file <- paste("graph", FL, "pdf", sep=".")
    plot_colors <- c("blue","red","forestgreen","black")
    pdf(file, height=4.5, width=9.5, onefile=TRUE)
    graphplot <- function(l, REG, tl, num) {
            dl <- REG[REG$region == l, tl]
            datel <- REG[REG$region == l, "date"]
            dl <- cbind(as.numeric(rownames(REG[REG$region == l, ])), REG[REG$region == l, tl])
            lines(dl, type="l", pch=2, col=plot_colors[num])
            num <- num + 1
    }
    drawGraph <- function(ab, y, z, s) {
            #Creating X axis
            x <- ab[ab$region == "Beta", z]
            y <- ab[,1]
            g_range <- range(0,x[!is.na(x)])
            plot(NA, type="l", col="orange", xlim= c(1, length(y)),  ylim=g_range,axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
            num=1
            sapply(unique(ab$region[ab$region]), FUN=graphplot, REG=ab, tl=z, num)
            box()
            axis(1, at=1:length(y), lab=FALSE)
            text(1:length(y), par("usr")[3] - 2, srt=45, adj=1.2, labels=y, xpd=T, cex=0.3)
            scale <- s
            axis(2, las=1, at=scale*0:g_range[2], cex.axis=0.3)
            main_title<-as.expression(z)
            #Caculationg Mean, Upper limit and lower limit using the below commands
            MEANLIMIT <- seq(length=length(y), from=mean(x), by=0)
            ULIMIT <- seq(length=length(y), from=mean(x) + 2.66*sum(abs(diff(x)))/length(x), by=0)
            LLIMIT <- seq(length=length(y), from=mean(x) - 2.66*sum(abs(diff(x)))/length(x), by=0)
            lines(MEANLIMIT, type="l", col="black")
            lines(ULIMIT, type="l", pch=2, lty=2, col="grey")
            lines(LLIMIT, type="l", pch=2, lty=2, col="black")
            title(main=main_title, col.main="red", font.main=4)
            title(xlab="Test Execution Date", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
            title(ylab="Millisecond", col.lab=rgb(0,0.5,0))
            legend("topright", g_range[2], main_title, cex=0.4, col=c("blue"), lty=1);
    }
    lab<-as.character(avg_data$date)
    AET <- avg_data$AveElapsedTime
    MTitle <- "AveElapsedTime"
    #Creating graph for Average Elapsed time
            drawGraph(avg_data, lab, MTitle, 5)
```

Here is the qes.tbl..

```
    date,region,AveElapsedTime
    5/1/2012,preprod,23
    5/2/2012,prod,76
    5/3/2012,Beta,34
    5/4/2012,prod,30
    5/5/2012,Beta,22
    5/6/2012,preprod,32
    5/7/2012,Beta,21
    5/8/2012,prod,44
    5/9/2012,preprod,45
    5/10/2012,Beta,23
    5/11/2012,prod,50
    5/13/2012,Beta,26
    5/14/2012,preprod,33
    5/15/2012,Beta,75
    5/16/2012,preprod,56
    5/17/2012,Beta,32
    5/18/2012,preprod,67
    5/19/2012,prod,40

    structure(list(date = structure(c(3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), .Label = c("5/10/2012", "5/11/2012", "5/1/2012", "5/13/2012", "5/14/2012", "5/15/2012", "5/16/2012", "5/17/2012", "5/18/2012", "5/19/2012", "5/2/2012", "5/3/2012", "5/4/2012", "5/5/2012", "5/6/2012", "5/7/2012", "5/8/2012", "5/9/2012"), class = "factor"), region = structure(c(2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3), .Label = c("Beta", "preprod", "prod"), class = "factor"), AveElapsedTime = c(23, 76, 34, 30, 22, 32, 21, 44, 45, 23, 50, 26, 33, 75, 56, 32, 67, 40)), .Names = c("date", "region", "AveElapsedTime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Comment: Post a reproducible version and I may have a look. I understand you don't want to use ggplot, but have you looked at lattice instead of base graphics?

Comment: Rather than pasting the data, paste the results of `dput(qes.tbl)` into your question. If you want me to work this question, make it reproducible. If I can copy and paste your code, and it works in my R session, I'll take a look, otherwise I'm moving on.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more help on how to do this.

Comment: Good, you're making progress. You're just a few steps away from making this reprodible.  Now add `avg_data <- ` before `stucture...`, then put it at the top of your code. Then start a clean R session, copy and paste your code. If it runs correctly (reproducing any behaviour you want us to see), then I should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following idea can be used

```
sapply(as.list(rep("w",20)),function(x){gsub("[^0-9]","",deparse(substitute(x)))})
```

to get an index

or alternatively you can use mapply

Another example

```
sapply(as.list(letters[1:20]),function(x){index<-gsub("[^0-9]","",deparse(substitute(x)));paste("i am index",index,"for letter",x)})
```

Comment: Why not just use `sapply(1:20, function(i)i)`?

Comment: Overly complicated, in my view: `x <- letters[1:20]; sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) paste("I am index", i, "for letter", x[i]))`